# Scala Nothing datatype

Tags: scala

I know Scala Nothing is the bottom type. When I see the API it extends from "Any" which is the top in the hierarchy.

Now since Scala does not support multiple inheritance, how can we say that it is the bottom type. In other words it is not inheriting directly all the classes or traits like Seq, List, String, Int and so on. If that is the case how can we say that it is the bottom of all type ?

What I meant is that if we are able to assign List[Nothing] (Nil) to List[String] as List is covariant in scala how it is possible because there is no direct correlation between Nothing and String type. As we know Nothing is a bottom type but I am having little difficulty in seeing the relation between String and Nothing as I stated in the above example.

Thanks & Regards,
Mohamed

Comment: `Nothing extends T` for all types `T`.  Thus, `Nothing extends String`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your question is, but the compiler knows `Nothing` and knows that it is a subtype of every other type because it is hardcoded in the compiler. There is not really a file Nothing.scala in the standard library that says `trait Nothing extends String with Int with Double with ...`.

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr summary**: `Nothing` is a subtype of every type because the spec says so. It cannot be explained from within the language. Every language (or at least almost every language) has some things at the very core that cannot be explained from within the language, e.g. `java.lang.Object` having no superclass even though every class has a superclass, since even if we don't write an `extends` clause, the class will implicitly get a superclass. Or the "bootstrap paradox" in Ruby, `Object` being an instance of `Class`, but `Class` being a subclass of `Object`, and thus `Object` being an indirect instance of itself (and even more directly: `Class` being an instance of `Class`).

---

> I know Scala Nothing is the bottom type. When I see the API it extends from "Any" which is the top in the hierarchy.
>
> Now since Scala does not support multiple inheritance, how can we say that it is the bottom type.

There are two possible answers to this.

The simple and short answer is: [because the spec says so](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#conformance). The spec says `Nothing` is a subtype of all types, so `Nothing` *is* the subtype of all types. How? We don't care. The spec says it is so, so that's what it is. Let the compiler designers worry about how to represent this fact within their compiler. Do you care how `Any` is able to have to superclass? Do you care how `def` is represented internally in the compiler?

The slightly longer answer is: Yes, it's true, `Nothing` inherits from `Any` and *only* from `Any`. But! Inheritance is not the same thing as subtyping. In Scala, inheritance and subtyping are closely tied together, but they are not the same thing. The fact that `Nothing` can only inherit from one class does not mean that it cannot be the subtype of more than one type. A type is not the same thing as a class.

In fact, to be very specific, the spec does not even say that `Nothing` is a subtype of all types. It only says that `Nothing` [*conforms to* all types](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#conformance).

> In other words it is not inheriting directly all the classes or traits like Seq, List, String, Int and so on. If that is the case how can we say that it is the bottom of all type ?

Again, we can say that, because the spec says we can say that.

How can we say that `def` defines a method? Because [the spec says so](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#function-declarations-and-definitions). How can we say that `a b c` means the same thing as `a.b(c)` and `a b_: c` means the same thing as `{ val __some_unforgeable_id__ = a; c.b_:(__some_unforgeable_id__) }`? Because [the spec says so](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#infix-operations). How can we say that `""` is a string and `''` is a character? Because [the spec says so](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#character-literals).

> What I meant is that if we are able to assign List[Nothing] (Nil) to List[String] as List is covariant in scala how it is possible because there is no direct correlation between Nothing and String type.

Yes, there *is* a direct correlation between the types `Nothing` and `String`. `Nothing` is a subtype of `String` because `Nothing` is a subtype of *all* types, including `String`.

> As we know Nothing is a bottom type but I am having little difficulty in seeing the relation between String and Nothing as I stated in the above example.

The relation between `String` and `Nothing` is that `Nothing` is a subtype of `String`. Why? Because the spec says so.

The compiler knows `Nothing` is a subtype of `String` the same way it knows `1` is an instance of `Int` and has a `+` method, even though if you look at the source code of the Scala standard library, [the `Int` class is actually abstract and all its methods have no implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/Int.scala).

[Someone, somewhere wrote some code within the compiler that knows how to handle adding two numbers](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/ScalaPrimitives.scala), even though those numbers are actually represented as JVM primitives and don't even exist inside the Scala object system. The same way, [someone, somewhere wrote some code within the compiler that knows that `Nothing` is a subtype of all types](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/tpe/TypeComparers.scala#L533) even though this fact is not represented (and is not even representable) in [the source code of `Nothing`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/runtime/Nothing%24.scala).

Comment: One of the most specification intensive answer I've seen in a while :)

Comment: I tried to re-iterate a sort-of "don't care" attitude by almost annoyingly often repeatedly pointing to the spec, because I feel that this "don't care" attitude lies at the heart of what programming is all about: abstraction and reuse. If the spec says that it works, then I don't care how it works, I just use it. (Actually, that's not true at all, I'm a curious guy and I am deeply interested in compilers and VMs and stuff, but I think it's a useful attitude to have towards using and even more importantly designing abstractions.)

Comment: I partially agree with that attitude. As you said yourself, there are eager developers who are truely interested in the tidbits of how the compiler makes `Nothing` a subtype of all types. I think a good answer should lead the path to discovering where that actually happens, for the curious minds. But I do agree that most of tge beginner question on SO aren't such.

Comment: Yes. And it annoys me that I haven't actually been able to find the specific code which implements the "bottom-ness" of `Nothing`. I had to cheat and simply link to the entire subdirectory containing the whole of the typechecker.

Comment: I think this is where the magic happens: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/tpe/TypeComparers.scala#L533

Comment: @Jasper-M: thanks, that looks good. And, of course, it's not in the "typechecker" directory, that would have been too easy :-D

Answer (score 3):

> Now since Scala does not support multiple inheritance

Scala does support multiple inheritance, using trait mixin. This is currently not commutative, i.e. the type `A with B` is not identical with `B with A` (this will happen with Dotty), but still it's a form of multiple inheritance, and indeed one of Scala's strong points, as it solves the diamond problem through its linearisation rules.

By the way, `Null` is another bottom type, inherited from Java (which could also be said to have a `Nothing` bottom type because you can throw a runtime exception in any possible place).

I think you need to distinguish between class inheritance and type bounds. There is no contradiction in defining `Nothing` as a bottom type, although it does not "explicitly" inherit from any type you want, such as `List`. It's more like a capability, the capability to throw an exception.

> if we are able to assign List[Nothing] (Nil) to List[String] as List is covariant in scala how it is possible because there is no direct correlation between Nothing and String type

Yes, the idea of the bottom type is that `Nothing` is also (among many other things) a sub-type of `String`. So you can write

```
def foo: String = throw new Exception("No")
```

This only works because `Nothing` (the type of throwing an exception) is more specific than the declared return type `String`.